# In iOS after session.startTunnel() connection status stops on connecting state

Tags: ios, vpn, openvpn, tunnel, networkextension

We are trying to connecting vpn (TCP & UDP) through “.ovpn” configuration using TunnelKit, But after calling startTunnel NEPacketTunnelProvider is not initiating.

Here's code:

```
private func makeProtocol() -> NETunnelProviderProtocol {


    let credentials = OpenVPN.Credentials(textUsername.text!, textPassword.text!)

    let configurationFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: “xyz”, withExtension: "ovpn")


    do {
        let file = try OpenVPN.ConfigurationParser.parsed(fromURL: configurationFileURL!).configuration
        var builder = OpenVPNTunnelProvider.ConfigurationBuilder(sessionConfiguration: file)
        builder.mtu = 1450
        builder.shouldDebug = true
        builder.masksPrivateData = false

        let configuration = builder.build()
        return try! configuration.generatedTunnelProtocol(
            withBundleIdentifier: ViewController2.tunnelIdentifier,
            appGroup: ViewController2.appGroup,
            credentials: credentials
        )
    } catch {
        print("Failed to send a message to the provider")
        return NETunnelProviderProtocol()
    }        
 }

func connect() {
    configureVPN({ (manager) in
        return self.makeProtocol()
    }, completionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("configure error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        self.currentManager?.isEnabled = true
        let session = self.currentManager?.connection as! NETunnelProviderSession
        do {
            try session.startTunnel()
            print("start Tunnel called")
        } catch let e {
            print("error starting tunnel: \(e)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi I have ovpn file, how can I use it for my iOS vpn app?